# How much reading is appropriate to give to students?

Tags: teaching, course-design

I'm designing an introductory undergraduate course on social science which is mostly based on not-so technical textbooks and articles (little math involved). Essays will be the key form of evaluation. I want to have an idea of how much readings to give to my students per week. The credit system my university uses is such that for 1 hour of contact teaching 1 hour of autonomous work is expected. I have 2 hours of contact teaching per week. If I assume students can read, say 20 pages per week (assume average article/journal size), I can give them 40 pages per week as background reading. This, I assume does not include their own study of textbooks (otherwise it would be impossible to give them readings!).

Do you have an idea of what sort of relation is used in terms of contact hours versus pages of reading?

Comment: Is this an intro course, upper level?

Comment: Too many variables here. there is "reading" and there is **reading**. There are readings you will discuss and others that are just "nice" to have seen". Testing on the readings? Etc.

Comment: Do you use ECTS credit system?

Comment: @BoatyMcboatface No. Why?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the focus of the class, and what other homework you are giving students.

Certain classes are expected to have more reading.  Societal and philosophical theory fields are heavy on reading, as are (obviously) literature classes.

Remember, different students will read at different rates, and the more you cover the less detail you can cover.  It's sometimes better to go into deeper depth than to cover more for both these reasons.

It is important you disclose the reading to students as early as possible, preferably before they apply for your class.  At the very least all major reading assignments longer than a few pages should be disclosed on the first day of class.  This gives students that need to time to read ahead.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [great resource](https://cte.rice.edu/blogarchive/2016/07/11/workload) which might be interesting to share here. It presents research on the topic done by others as well as conducted by themselves. The key to me is the table they show, reproduced below:

[image]

So, of course, the answer is always it depends, but this at least gives a nice baseline from which to work on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably over estimating what an undergraduate can read.

Things might be different in soc sci, as compared to natural science (where I am), but even for a paper without much in the way of math, I tend to allow, say 3 hours for a student to read an average research article (I takes me an hour, and i've been doing it for 20 years).